# We are deploying Open Loyalty on to Google Cloud and we are receiving a Yarn error?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, hadoop-yarn, google-kubernetes-engine

We are installing Open Loyalty Program on to the Google Cloud. Please Google Open Loyalty by Divante Ltd.

We have been trying to deploy this application on google cloud using Kubernetes.
The instance used to deploy this application contains Debian v4.9 as its OS. And we installed Docker, GCloud, Kubernetes and Kompose as the tools for deployment. We built two docker images for the frontend and backend and linked them to the docker-compose file. Now in frontend image, we used (node:5) image from docker hub in Dockerfile of the frontend.

We also changed the docker-compose file as seen below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Ufg.png)

After changing the docker-compose file, we ran “kompose up” within the same directory.
which created the deployment and service ‘yaml’ file and then proceeded to run it.
We have pods as given below, but the frontend pod shows some error and some logs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwMsh.png)

It says yarn not found. When we execute the same process on a local machine, it works as expected.

We are also trying to seek help from Google Support but your help and suggestions will also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Google will not help you installing your software unless you pay for platinum support and in that case they would be helping you already.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn is available from `node:6`. Your front-end image is too old.

Comment: We had a similar error even after we upgraded it to node:6